# Plugins for acorn loose_parser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

This code snippet seems not work, why?

```
var acorn = require("./node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn_loose");

/* Extend default Acorn's methods.*/
acorn.pluginsLoose.testPlug = function(looseParser) {
    looseParser.extend('finishNode', function(nextMethod) {
        return function(node, type) {
            console.log(node, type);
            return nextMethod.call(this, node, type);
        };
    });
};

var res = acorn.parse_dammit("alert(1", {ecmaVersion: 6, plugins: {testPlug: true}});

console.log(res)
```

Give us next error:

```
...\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:508
  if (!plugin) throw new Error("Plugin '" + name + "' not found")
                   ^

Error: Plugin 'testPlug' not found
    at Parser.loadPlugins (...\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:508:26)
    at new Parser (...\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:444:10)
    at Object.tokenizer (...\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3115:12)
    at new LooseParser (...\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn_loose.js:15:23)
    at Object.parse_dammit (...\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn_loose.js:1258:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\plugins_poc.js:16:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Is it bug or I do something wrong?

Enviroment: idea intellij 16.

> Update:

Chrome give the similar error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = acorn.parse_dammit("alert(1", {ecmaVersion: 6, plugins: {testPlug: true}});
```

You need to use `pluginsLoose` instead of `plugins` here as well!